# Is there a list of all (or most of the) possible combinations of (extended) grapheme clusters?

Tags: java, character-encoding, utf-16, grapheme, grapheme-cluster

So, I'm looking into coding some binary data as text, using single graphical units, after using already all the available ones for Java and UTF16, I'd like to expand my "pool".

I recently discovered grapheme clusters, where you can combine different elements/chars in order to create a single graphical unit, or, as they are properly called, a grapheme cluster.

For example: "‍♂️", which holds:

- base character
- skintone modifier
- ligature character (zero width joiner)
- male sign
- variation selector

(more [here](https://hsivonen.fi/string-length/) or [here](https://ardislu.dev/biggest-unicode-grapheme-cluster))

I wonder if there is a comprensive list of all the possibile combinations, or at least some specifications which state clearly which emoticons can be combined how and how long they can be at maximum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the obvious starting point is unicode itself: https://unicode.org

It does not provide a single, comprehensive list, as far as I know, but several lists for groups of symbols, e.g.

Emojis without modifiers:
https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Emojis with modifiers:
https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-modifiers.html